Logic to check whether a two DATE FIELDS are exactly has one month gap (same DATE) i.e. 28 Feb & 28 Mar
Context:
I'd like to check whether the date from field B is ONE MONTH ahead of the date from field A. However, the definition of ONE MONTH is: field B date has exactly the same date with field A date.
Table Example:



date_a
date_b
flag




2024-01-05
2024-02-04
FALSE


2024-01-05
2024-02-05
TRUE



My Failed Trial:
...

CASE WHEN DATE_DIFF(date_b, date_a, MONTH) = 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS flag

...

However, that logic only takes into account the MONTH, without considering the date itself.
Any suggestion on this? Thanks!

An option could be use EXTRACT function to get the day from date and compare it:
CASE 
  WHEN 
    DATE_DIFF(date_b, date_a, MONTH) = 1 
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_a) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_b)
  THEN TRUE 
  ELSE FALSE
END AS flag

Another approach using DATE_ADD:
(DATE_ADD(date_b, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = date_a) AS flag


Hi Damião, thanks for the suggestion. Actually, that's also the workaround that I've implemented and it works. I wonder whether BQ has another simpler way to do this, perhaps any function that they created.

@IrenRamadhan another option could be use the DATE_ADD function. I add an example in the answer.

Wow, actually that's simpler and also works. Thanks, Damião!
